# Is there a way to run C# Method in Visual Studio 2019 in design mode?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019, c#-interactive

I want to test my method quickly, and it would be great if I could just run the method and it can give me output in design mode. I tried with C# Interactive since I realized that is exactly what I need but for some reason, it is not working. It does not output the debug line and all of the lines are underlined red. Am I using it wrong? (Using 2019 VS Free edition)
[image]

Comment: This is why we have unit tests. You can test your methods from the Test Explorer in Visual Studio. Hopefully it is also available in the free edition. Not that I rule out C# Interactive, which has a different use, but just so you know.

Comment: You cannot define methods in the immediate window, but statements like `Console.WriteLine("Hello");` work fine.

Comment: Unit tests also work in VS Community Edition

Comment: Thanks, all. To be honest, its a little disappointing to need to write a unit test just to test one lousy method quickly, thought C# Interactive is meant just for that. I'll try with unit testing then